# java - short circuit after using |

Tags: java, short-circuiting, bitwise-or, logical-or

I was doing a problem on dmoj and it says that there is a short circuit error.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       String[] ND = input.nextLine().split(" ");
       if(ND.length > 2) return;
       int[] ND_NUM = new int[ND.length];
       for(int i = 0; i < ND.length; i++){
         ND_NUM[i] = Integer.parseInt(ND[i]);
       }
       if(ND_NUM[0] < 1 | ND_NUM[0] > 10000) return;
       if(ND_NUM[1] < -10000 | ND_NUM[1] > 10000) return;
       String[] INTERVALS = input.nextLine().split(" ");
       int[] INTERVALS_NUM = new int[INTERVALS.length];
       for(int i = 0; i < INTERVALS.length; i++){
         INTERVALS_NUM[i] = Integer.parseInt(INTERVALS[i]);
       }

       int interval = ND_NUM[0];
       int timeToGo = ND_NUM[1];
       for(int i = 0; i < INTERVALS_NUM.length; i++){
         if(INTERVALS_NUM[i] == timeToGo/interval | INTERVALS_NUM[i] == (timeToGo/interval)*-1){
           System.out.print(INTERVALS_NUM[i]);
           return;
         }
       }
       System.out.print("This is not the best time for a trip.");
    }
}
```

I read in another post that to prevent short circuit errors, use single `|` instead of `||`.  However, when I switched my if statements to use the single `|`, it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Bitwise-OR `|` is not logical-OR `||`. They have completely different meaning.

Comment: @xiaofeng.li When dealing with `boolean`s, it isn't bitwise. It's a non-short-circuiting version of `||`.

Comment: What is the actual error you're seeing?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am not gettig an error in the text editor however when I submit it to DMOJ I get a short circuit error.

Comment: So does it tell you the actual error?  Or do you just have to guess?  Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It gives no message, or where it is, just says "Test case: -"(- meaning short circuit)

Comment: Ah, thanks, it's actually a real concept. Cool

Comment: Well, without knowing what problem you were solving, I can't tell you whether you've solved it correctly.  But syntactically, your code looks fine.  And without knowing what test cases DMOJ applies, there's no way I can tell you what's going wrong.  I doubt whether anyone will be able to answer this question to your satisfaction.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Ah okay, thanks for the quick replies anyways!  If you want to know the question I am working on its called troubling times by xXxP0t4t0MStRxXx

Comment: Ok, so it's not necessary to use the non-short-circuiting OR because there are no side-effects involved in all the conditions.